# how to set background for blackberry

Tags: blackberry

i have used the following to set a background for blackberry ..no errors but in the output
 when i scroll down the image gets repeated .. how to solve this problem .please help me

```
  public final class MyScreen extends MainScreen
    {
      Bitmap background;
    public MyScreen()
    {  

     background = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("CVMS.jpg");
         VerticalFieldManager vfm = new VerticalFieldManager(USE_ALL_HEIGHT | USE_ALL_WIDTH |  
            VerticalFieldManager.NO_VERTICAL_SCROLL);
            vfm.setBackground(BackgroundFactory.createBitmapBackground(Bitmap.getBitmapResource("CVMS.jpg"),Background.POSITION_X_LEFT,Background.POSITION_Y_TOP,Background.REPEAT_INHERIT));  


          add(vfm);

              }
   }
  this is my complete code
```

Answer (score 3):

All you need to do is change a flag in the following line

```
vfm.setBackground(BackgroundFactory.createBitmapBackground(Bitmap.getBitmapResource("CVMS.jpg"),Background.POSITION_X_LEFT, Background.POSITION_Y_TOP, Background.REPEAT_SCALE_TO_FIT));
```

You just need to use `REPEAT_SCALE_TO_FIT` instead of `REPEAT_INHERIT`

Comment: initially i used that Background.REPEAT_SCALE_TO_FIT then it showed java error 104 Uncaught:illegalArgumentException .. then after i changed to Background.REPEAT_INHERIT then i got the output but when i scroll down the image gets repeated . so how to solve that

Comment: That's weird...how about doing `this.getMainManager().setBackground(BackgroundFactory.createBitmapBackground(Bitmap.getBitmapResource("CVMS.jpg"),Background.POSITION_X_LEFT, Background.POSITION_Y_TOP, Background.REPEAT_SCALE_TO_FIT));`
if it suits your case

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using Background.REPEAT_NONE ?